# CHAID Decision Tree in R or Python

Tags: python, r, package, decision-tree

I've used SPSS to generate a CHAID tree.It does an automatic binning of continuous variables and returns Chi-squared value and Degrees of freedom which is not found in the summary function of R.Below is a partial sample output.

```
    Node    0               1               Total        PC Parent  Variable    Sig.a   Chi-Square  df  Split Values
        N   Percent      N  Percent        N    Percent                         
    0   148025  84.0%   28111   16.0%   176136  100.0%   0                      
    1   102390  93.9%   6643    6.1%    109033  61.9%    0    0     SALES1      0.000   42991.370   4   <= .000
    2   12600   91.3%   1194    8.7%    13794   7.8%     0    0     SALES1      0.000   42991.370   4   (.000,149.990]
    3   15140   83.7%   2942    16.3%   18082   10.3%    0    0     SALES1      0.000   42991.370   4   (149.990,1044.000]
```

What R returns is this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32739093/what-are-the-available-chaid-summary-functions-in-r

I've found ways to tap into the tree output and play around with it like this example:

[chaid regression tree to table conversion in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428508/chaid-regression-tree-to-table-conversion-in-r)

Are there functions to get a SPSS kind of output in R or python or must it all be done manually with the partykit package in R?

Answer (score 3):

I recently wrote an open-source package in python for CHAID [here](https://github.com/Rambatino/CHAID)

Comment: I am facing issues while installing.
extern "Python": function Cryptography_locking_cb() called, but @ffi.def_extern() was not called in the current subinterpreter.  Returning 0.

Comment: I literally have no idea how I'm meant to solve that. If you have an issue create an issue on github, but you'll have to detail all the relevant package versions/operating system/commands etc...

Comment: Dude, is there any particular reason to not follow the .fit & .predict way as in sklearn ?

Comment: It was never written to predict - it gave an estimate of how good the fit was on the data given. It should be trivial to write those functions

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [CHAID](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=343) package from r-forge link? It does well in performing CHAID analysis. However, all the variables need to be categorical / factors in order for it to work.